# If else regex in jQuery validation doesn't`t work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I am trying to match a complex if else regex pattern using `jquery.validation`

//My regex

```
(?=^abc1)(^abc1[-]dba\d*.csv)|(?=^def2)(^def2[-]dba\d*.xls|txt)|(?=^ghi3)(^ghi3[-]dba\d*.xls)|(?=^xyz4)(^xyz4[-]dba\d*.csv)
```

// Example

abc1-dba.csv

Tried over here : http://www.regexr.com/ it matches

But in the code it is not matching anything.

//I call the validate function inside which :-

```
rules : {    
  param : {
    required : true,
    pattern: "(?=^abc1)(^abc1[-]dba\d*.csv)|(?=^def2)(^def2[-]dba\d*.xls|txt)|(?=^ghi3)(^ghi3[-]dba\d*.xls)|(?=^xyz4)(^xyz4[-]dba\d*.csv)"
  }
}
```

doesn't work.

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VQ226/1/

Comment: Doesnt work if I search abc1-dba10.csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some errors in your regex, but the reason it's failing on `abc1-dba10.csv` is because you're writing the regex as a string literal and you forgot to escape the backslashes.  Your `\d*` should be `\\d*`.

As for the errors, the most significant one is where you test for `.xls` or `.txt` extensions.  You need to isolate that part in its own group, like this: `\.(?:xls|txt)`.  You also forgot to escape the period, not just in that spot but everywhere.  (You would probably never get bitten by that one, but it is a bug.)

Aside from that, you've got way more start anchors (`^`) than you need, but you left out the end anchor (`$`) entirely.  And those lookaheads aren't doing anything useful.  If the string matches the regex `^abc1[-]dba\d*.csv`, then *of course* a lookahead like `(?=^abc)` at the beginning of the string will succeed.  Here's how I would write it:

```
"^(?:abc1-dba\\d*\\.csv|def2-dba\\d*\\.(?:xls|txt)|ghi3-dba\\d*\\.xls|xyz4-dba\\d*\\.csv)$
```

If you can use a regex literal instead, use this:

```
/^(?:abc1-dba\d*\.csv|def2-dba\d*\.(?:xls|txt)|ghi3-dba\d*\.xls|xyz4-dba\d*\.csv)$/
```